# How to use async/await in jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

I noticed that jasmine v2.7.0 added support for async/await in `before`, `after` and `it` functions. But I cannot find how to actually use it. I tried to look into the documentation but they still refer to the `done` callback on a regular function.

Anyone knows how to start using this?